# Mysql 2 tables count query too slow

Tags: mysql

I need help with mysql query, got 2 counting tables joined on primary table. Its about user activities - counting and suming their activities (comments and articles) into one variable and then ordering it by DESC. Main table is **users**, secundary are **articles** and **comments**.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.avatar,
   IF(comm.id, COUNT(DISTINCT comm.id), 0) AS count_comments,
   IF(comm.votes, SUM(DISTINCT comm.votes), 0) AS count_comments_votes,
   IF(article.id, COUNT(article.id), 0) AS count_articles,
   IF(article.views, SUM(DISTINCT article.views), 0) AS count_articles_views,
   (IF(comm.id AND comm.votes>2, COUNT(comm.id)*50, 0) + IF(comm.votes, SUM(comm.votes)*10, 0) + IF(article.id, COUNT(article.id)*200, 0) + IF(article.views, SUM(article.views)*1, 0)) AS points
FROM users AS u
   LEFT JOIN comments AS comm ON comm.id_user=u.id AND comm.date>='2013-05-01' AND comm.date<='2013-06-24'
   LEFT JOIN articles AS article ON article.id_user=u.id AND article.date>='2013-05-01' AND article.date<='2013-06-24'
   WHERE u.is_active='1'
   GROUP BY u.id
   HAVING points>0
   ORDER BY points DESC
```

Query took about **`11-13`** sec to finish which is too long. Any ideas ? Maybe indexing some fields could speed up the query ?

Comment: 1. `EXPLAIN` 2. Table definitions for every table used in this query 3. Don't expect too much - the query is terrible

Comment: indexing date and is_active columns might help

Comment: @chetan: I bet `u.is_active` accepts only 2 values 0 and 1, thus with such cardinality mysql won't use it.

Comment: use explain before your query.

Comment: Like @zerkms said, use `EXPLAIN` and show us table definitions. If you don't know how to, google "MYSQL EXPLAIN" and "MYSQL SHOW CREATE TABLE". Also, we need to know what table engine you're using and whether you configured it or not. Default settings are made so MySQL can work with old computers and is very slow out of the box. On the other hand, your query doesn't look as it's written with efficiency in mind, seeing you have `HAVING` in there.

Comment: @zerkms thx will try to do something, I know the query is terrible, thats why i need some help ;) Storage engine is InnoDB